# How to have output of script emailed from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, build-automation, jenkins-plugins

I am setting up a Jenkins job that processes some data.

Once the job is finished, I would like to have jenkins run a script that describes the status of the recent processing and email the stdout of that script to a specified email address.

While I realize that it is possible to have the script send the email itself, I am wondering if there exists a more ideal way to have Jenkins send the output of that script. Is there a plugin that is idea for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but the [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin for Jenkins sounds like it may do what you want.

Answer (score 19):

To configure the **Email-ext** plugin:

To get a portion of the log in the mail, if not all, set the 'Extended E-mail Notification' to send an email for each build that failed, and use the **$BUILD_LOG** in the body of the message:

1. In the body of the message (below the '$DEFAULT_CONTENT' ) add the parameter **$BUILD_LOG**  to display the end of the build log
2. Assuming the log is in plain-text, change '*Content Type*' to **Plain Text**

For the list of built-in Jenkins parameters, go to this page:

- `http://[your-jenkins-server]/env-vars.html`

Cheers

**EDIT:**

To get to that list of available env-vars via the UI, 
there is a link at the **Execute shell** build-step, for example -

[image: Link to Env-Vars list via the UI]

Comment: $BUILD_LOG truncates 250 lines, so if you want more, you can do something like {BUILD_LOG, maxLines=8000}

Comment: @grayaii must be `${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=8000}` - is missing the `$`

Comment: @Gonen The URL mentioned works as expected (copy/paste) directly in the browser address bar, but through the GUI of Jenkins itself, in what section and where is the link that refers to that URL?

Comment: @manuel-jordan that is a very good question... have edited my answer to show it can be accessed via a link in the **Execute shell** build-step

Comment: @Gonen Thanks for the quick support - to be honest I thought: in the same way if there is the `Jenkins CLI` section (it how an option available through `Manage Jenkins`) where exists available a link to get the `jar` file - is curious that does not exist something similar to get the `Environment Variables` without to create a `Job` - I mean a new section/option available straightforward through `Manage Jenkins`